# MySQL Insert with skipping duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL. I am getting a user phonebook from their mobile device, and I am saving into a database.

Table Phonebook (User ID is INT)

```
INSERT INTO `Phonebook`
            (`user_id`, `first_name`, `mobile`)
    VALUES(4,'tom','+919810012345');
```

It works fine, but if user again upload his phonebook then I want to skip users existing contacts and add only new one from his/her phonebook and the data can be compare with *user_id, first_name, mobile* and these columns can't be duplicate.

If the user has *+919810012345* and the next time *9810012345/9810-0123-45* then add again to the database.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
INSERT Phonebook (`user_id`, `first_name`, `mobile`)
    Values (SELECT `user_id`, `first_name`, `mobile`
            FROM Phonebook
            where `user_id` != $user_id
            AND `first_name` !=$name
            AND `mobile` != $phn)
```

#### Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `Phonebook` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `mobile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3520 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

#### Phone Book Table

Table Name: *PhoneBook*

```
id  user_id first_name   mobile
1   100      John        +91981000000
2   100      Tom         91981000001
3   100      Ron         9810-000-02
4   100      Mat         91981000003
5   100      Miley       981000004
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @erik258 As you can see i need to compare user_id first_name and mobile and also mobile number can be in different variations. Duplicate key is not for me. Correct me if i am wrong please

Comment: can you add more data example

Comment: `UNIQUE(user_id, first_name, mobile)`

Comment: @nbk Please check data in updated question

Comment: @shingo Can you please show me in query thsis will be helpful for me

Comment: If I were you I will write a few lines of php statements to check whether there exists a record with same user_id, first_name and mobile, and then perform the insert query if the result is negative

Comment: @KenLee If i loop around database with large objects and checking one by one in php then i don't think it will efficient way to do that.

Comment: In modern servers it will not be a problem. (nowadays programmer time is **usually** more precious than CPU time/resources), but if you insist then please continue to use a single query to do what you want.

Comment: @KenLee Thanks for the suggestion but dear we are on AWS with live project and as our engineers try to reduce every single second user wait time. I am not sure about how much your suggested way can impact but i saying because it's another step to execute before execute real query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a UNIQUE constraint

```
CREATE TABLE `Phonebook` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `mobile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE (`user_id`, `first_name`, `mobile`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3520 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```
INSERT INTO `Phonebook`
            (`user_id`, `first_name`, `mobile`)
    VALUES(4,'tom','+919810012345');
```

```
SELECT * FROM `Phonebook`
```

| id | user_id | first_name | mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3520 | 4 | tom | +919810012345 |

```
INSERT INTO `Phonebook`
            (`user_id`, `first_name`, `mobile`)
    VALUES(4,'tom','+919810012345')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = user_id;
```

```
SELECT * FROM `Phonebook`
```

| id | user_id | first_name | mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3520 | 4 | tom | +919810012345 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bZ8Zn6qG)

Comment: So first i need to make these column unique? then if user again try to upload his phone book then it will only add new numbers/name in table and skip the rest? and by making unique does it mean it will skip only if all three values are matched?

Comment: yes exactly. like i said play around with more data, and you can see hiw ir works, but when all three already exist, it will not insert them any more, change one and it will be entered. it will not detect if tom ha s changed his number ´, then it will add another row, but you can refine the process to detect updates, by making only user_id and name unique and replace the ON DUPLICATE UPDATE mobile = VALUES(mobile)

Comment: I tried fiddle and first remove + then 91 from phone number but second time it's not creating any entries into database

Comment: then o really don't understand why you are trying see https://dbfiddle.uk/2n8IAeY-